# Getting "no matching key exchange method found" when using SSH between identical Ubuntu 20.04 LTS servers

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

I have 2 identical Ubuntu 20.04 LTS servers (actually one is a clone of the other in VMWare), and when I try doing SFTP or SSH from one server to another, I am getting

> no matching key exchange method found.
> Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com

I am getting this no matter which way I try and connect.
Any help would be appreciated.

## UPDATE 3

```
ewessel@unifyed-new-db:~$ sudo sshd -T | grep ciphers | perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' | sort -u
aes128-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

## UPDATE 2

In the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/` directory on both machines, I found a file called `weak.conf` that had the following:

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

## UPDATE 1

Below is a verbose listing of what is happening during the ssh connection:

```
ewessel@unifyed-new-db:~$ ssh -vvv ewessel@xx.xx.xx.xx
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.50.1.210 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.50.1.210:22 as 'ewessel'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ewessel/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug3: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
```

Comment: You will need to provide information about how you have configured login to the servers in order for anyone to help.

Comment: May sound trivial, but if the other is a clone of the first one, did you generate different public/private keys for SSH?

Comment: Use `ssh -v .....` to get more information.

Comment: in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ directory on both machines, I found a file called weak.conf that had the following:  KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Comment: Re: UPDATE 3, these look the same as what I have. I was probably barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Try this command:  `sudo mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/weak.conf /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/weak.conf_original`. Followed by: `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`. If this does not work revert the file name change by: `sudo mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/weak.conf_original /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/weak.conf` and then restart the sshd service again.